# Possible to prevent MySQL from renaming key after 'UNCOMPRESS'?

Tags: php, mysql, associative, compression

So I'm storing some XML in a table, and using the MySQL 'COMPRESS' function like this:

```
$query = "SELECT UNCOMPRESS(table_row) FROM database WHERE this = 'that'";
$mysqli = $this->ConnectDB();
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$task_result = $task->fetch_assoc();
```

This works of course, but it renames the key within the returned associative array from `'table_row'` to `'UNCOMPRESS(table_row)'`.

Is there a way to prevent this renaming?

Comment: Just add an alias to the expression in the SELECT list.  `SELECT UNCOMPRESS(table_row) AS table_row FROM `. Whatever alias you assign in the SQL text is what MySQL will return in the resultset metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT UNCOMPRESS(table_row) AS table_row 
          FROM database WHERE this = 'that'";
```